# java.lang.RuntimeException with android application

Tags: java, android, runtimeexception

I'm having problems with my application. Shortly after compiling, the application randomly closes. Checking LogCat shows that it is a java.lang.RuntimeException. I've been through all of the forum posts on this, and have changed my code accordingly, but the problem still persists. Help?

Code:

```
public class DroidzActivity extends Activity implements OnGesturePerformedListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private GestureLibrary mLibrary;
private static final String TAG = MainThread.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new MainGamePanel(this));
    //requesting to turn the title OFF
    //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //make it full screen
    //getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    // set the MainGamePanel as the View

    Log.d(TAG, "View added");

    mLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
    if (!mLibrary.load()) {
        finish();
    }

    GestureOverlayView gestures = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gestures);
    gestures.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);

}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Destroying...");
    super.onDestroy();
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Stopping...");
    super.onStop();
}

public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
    ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = mLibrary.recognize(gesture);
    if (predictions.size() > 0) {
        if (predictions.get(0).score > 1.0) {
            String action = predictions.get(0).name;
            if ("action_add".equals(action)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Adding a contact", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if ("action_delete".equals(action)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Removing a contact", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if ("action_refresh".equals(action)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Reloading contacts", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
02-08 23:16:54.898: D/MainThread(3027): View added
02-08 23:16:54.937: D/AndroidRuntime(3027): Shutting down VM
02-08 23:16:54.937: W/dalvikvm(3027): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
02-08 23:16:54.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3027): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-08 23:16:54.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3027): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.obviam.droidz/net.obviam.droidz.DroidzActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-08 23:16:54.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3027):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
02-08 23:16:54.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3027):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
02-08 23:16:54.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3027):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-08 23:16:54.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3027):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
02-08 23:16:54.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3027):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-08 23:16:54.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3027):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-08 23:16:54.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3027):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
02-08 23:16:54.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3027):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-08 23:16:54.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3027):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-08 23:16:54.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3027):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
02-08 23:16:54.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3027):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
02-08 23:16:54.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3027):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-08 23:16:54.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3027): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-08 23:16:54.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3027):     at net.obviam.droidz.DroidzActivity.onCreate(DroidzActivity.java:42)
02-08 23:16:54.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3027):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-08 23:16:54.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3027):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
02-08 23:16:54.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3027):     ... 11 more
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="net.obviam.droidz"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity
        android:name=".DroidzActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Please upload your code and the Manifest file.

Comment: Please post your logcat and entire code.

Comment: If you read through the exception in LogCat, you'll probably find one or more "Caused by" lines followed another exception. Find the last "Caused by" and post the exception that follows it. That's the original problem. Please post that here and we can help you.

Comment: check at which line you are having this error.

Comment: Does this help? Sorry, I'm very new to this. 

It looks as if it is caused by a nullpointer exception... I'm not quite sure where that's at though.

Comment: It tells you: ActivityThread.Java line 1651.

Comment: Yes. But more specificly `NullPointerException` on DroidzActivity.java at line 42 (look at the bottom side of the exception list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up resolving the problem by implementing a FrameView, then using frameLayout.addView(). A better explanation can be found in this tutorial [here.](http://scanplaygames.com/?p=168)

A big thanks to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 0):

On `setContentView()` you set your view to `MainGamePanel()`. Now on this line `GestureOverlayView gestures = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gestures);`
 you are trying to get a view from a resource identifier. But resource id will generate automatically only from xml at compile time.

You sould set your content view to xml. Or if the MainGamePanel is a ViewGroup create a method to get the `GestureOverlayView` from `MainGamePanel`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't think MainGamePanel is a view group, but it is kinda embedded in everything else I've written. What would a method that got GestureOverlayView from MainGamePanel look like?

Comment: write your own method. return the `GettureOverlayView` at the end if you have one.